# How this.handleSetRating(i + 1) is working in StarRating component?

Tags: javascript, closures

This is the StarRating component =>

```js
class StarRating extends Component {
  state = {
    rating: 0,
  };
  renderStars = () => {
    let stars = [];
    let maxRating = 5;

    for (let i = 0; i < maxRating; i++) {
      stars.push(
        <Star
          isSelected={this.state.rating > i}
          setRating={() => this.handleSetRating(i + 1)}
          key={i}
        />
      );
    }
    return stars;
  };
  handleSetRating = (rating) => {
    if (this.state.rating === rating) {
      this.setState({ rating: 0 });
    } else {
      this.setState({ rating });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <ul className="course--stars">{this.renderStars()}</ul>;
  }
}
```

And this is the Star component =>

```js
const Star = (props) => (
  <li 
    className={props.isSelected ? "selected" : null} 
    onClick={props.setRating}>
    <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16 15" className="star">
      <path
        d="M8.5,0.3l2,4.1c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.3l4.6,0.7c0.4,0.1,0.6,0.6,0.3,0.9l-3.3,3.2c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.3-0.2,0.5l0.8,4.5
      c0.1,0.4-0.4,0.8-0.8,0.6l-4.1-2.1c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5,0l-4.1,2.1c-0.4,0.2-0.9-0.1-0.8-0.6l0.8-4.5c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.2-0.5L0.2,6.2
      C-0.2,5.9,0,5.4,0.5,5.3L5,4.7c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.3l2-4.1C7.7-0.1,8.3-0.1,8.5,0.3z"
      />
    </svg>
  </li>
);
```

How this.handleSetRating() function inside the loop is working when onClick function calls it on the Star component?

---

To be precise I am getting confused when the for loop runs, does `setRating()` on Star component get *resolved straight away and calls this.handleSetRating(i + 1)*; which when happen will lead to an infinite loop, or it is using **closure** to remember the ith value after each iteration so when it was called by the `onClick` on Star component it uses a **closure** to use I value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...or it is using closure to remember the ith value after each iteration so when it was called by the `onClick` on Star component it uses a closure to use `i` value

That's what it's doing. It works because `i` is declared in the `for` loop initialization part using `let`. It wouldn't work correctly if `i` were declared outside the loop, or if it were declared with `var`.

Here's a simpler example:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(i), i * 200);
}
```

The function passed into `setTimeout` is like the function being used in your `onClick`. The function's code isn't called during the `for` loop, it's called *later*. But it has a reference to the copy of `i` that existed when it was created. When you use `let` in a `for` loop initializer, a **different** `i` is created for each loop iteration.

Comment: Just for confirmation does the closure will be created around the anonymous inside the setTimeout() function ??

Comment: @PrashantSunwar - The anonymous function is the closure. It has a link on it to the environment where it was created. That link is used by the JavaScript engine to set the parent environment of the function call when the function is called.